# ansible (include_vars) from include

Tags: ansible, cisco

upgrading from [Unable to open shell: Ansible v2.3.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44981599/unable-to-open-shell-ansible-v2-3-1-0)

I run into,

> [DEPRECATION WARNING]: include is kept for backwards compatibility but usage is discouraged. The module documentation 
>       details page may explain more about this rationale.. This feature will be removed in a future release. Deprecation 
>       warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.

#### from

```
---
- hosts: ios
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local

  tasks:

  - name: obtain login credentials
    include_vars: secrets.yml

  - name: define provider
    set_fact:
      provider:
        host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ creds['username'] }}"
        password: "{{ creds['password'] }}"
        #Uncomment next line if enable password is needed
        #auth_pass: "{{ creds['auth_pass'] }}"
        transport: cli

  - include: tasks/ios_command-freeform.yml
```

what is the proper way of using `include_vars` to involve a folder content? (Trying to use this instead but yml-s inside "`tasks`" end up getting ignored by the main play).

#### Thanks in advance

```
[root@ymlhost-3 ansible-yml]# cat cisco-play.yml 
---
- name: cisco-yml
  hosts: cisco
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local

  tasks:

  - name: obtain login credentials
    include_vars: secrets.yml

  - name: define provider
    set_fact:
      provider:
        host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ creds['username'] }}"
        password: "{{ creds['password'] }}"
        auth_pass: "{{ creds['auth_pass'] }}"
        authorize: yes

  - name: Include all .yml
    include_vars:
      dir: 'tasks'
      extensions:
          - json
          - yml
[root@ymlhost-3 ansible-yml]#
```

#### also tried different form

```
[root@ymlhost-3 ansible-yml]# cat cisco-play.yml 
---
- name: cisco-yml
  hosts: cisco
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local

  tasks:

  - name: obtain login credentials
    include_vars: secrets.yml

  - name: define provider
    set_fact:
      provider:
        host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ creds['username'] }}"
        password: "{{ creds['password'] }}"
        auth_pass: "{{ creds['auth_pass'] }}"
        authorize: yes

  - name: Include all .yml files except bastion.yml (2.3)
    include_vars:
      dir: 'vars'
      ignore_files: 'bastion.yml'
      extensions: ['yml']
[root@ymlhost-3 ansible-yml]#
```

Comment: What is the question, what is the problem, where is the code with `include`? Including variables has nothing to do with it, you are troubleshooting wrong parts of your code.

Comment: updated. if i switch back to old include statement, it works. but newer 
 one doesn't

Comment: Around 90% of your question is irrelevant to the problem. The remaining part can be solved by spending a minute to ponder the meaning of the warning, instead of shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible is telling you the `include` directive has been deprecated and will not work in future versions, [reference](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/include_module.html):

> **include - include a play or task list.**
>
> **DEPRECATED**
>
> The include action was too confusing, dealing with both plays and tasks, being both dynamic and static. This module will be removed in version 2.8. As alternatives use include_tasks, import_playbook, import_tasks.

---

Replace:

```
- include: tasks/ios_command-freeform.yml
```

With:

```
- import_tasks: tasks/ios_command-freeform.yml
```

Or:

```
- include_tasks: tasks/ios_command-freeform.yml
```

Difference is explained here: [Differences Between Static and Dynamic](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_reuse.html#differences-between-static-and-dynamic). There is likely no difference in your use case, so go with `import_tasks`.

Comment: works beautifully. thank you for your time. i should have googled more carefully